# How change BO product list to also show wholesale price Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Someone who has made this change?

Today the BO product list show the end customer price excl and incl vat.
I want if possible to show our wholesale price and mour end customer price excl vat instead. This is probably a change in AdminProductController but I dont know how. I run PS 1.6.1.6

Regards

Anders Yuran

Answer (score 0):

Open /controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php from your PrestaShop root directory and in the __construct() function, you will see the following code:

```
$this->fields_list['price'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Base price'),
        'type' => 'price',
        'align' => 'text-right',
        'filter_key' => 'a!price'
    );
```

This code is responsible for showing the price in products list, try replacing the code with the following:

```
$this->fields_list['price'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('WholeSale price'),
        'type' => 'price',
        'align' => 'text-right',
        'filter_key' => 'a!wholesale_price'
    );
```

Hope it helps.